# Determine the space taken up between restarts

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

There is this nasty bug in some software that IT is using that uses up hard drive space for no reason. Moreover IT has been completely unable and unwilling to help me permanently resolve this issue. That is, it will eat up all but a few megabytes until the computer is restarted.

The issue is temporarily resolved by restarting the computer. That is, as soon as I restart the computer, the hard drive reverts to its original size in free space. As I have a 120 GB hard drive, with all but 1 GB used up by stuff I can't control, it can force me to restart my computer multiple times a day.

Is there some software that detects what has changed between reboots so that I may write a script to locate and delete these files every time this issue crops up?

If it helps, I have local admin rights to my computer so I can modify just about any file on the computer.

Comment: I am hesitant to suggest this but, you can use Autoruns, to one by one load each application that normally runs.

Comment: Be kind to it ...